# GC skew method using sliding window concept in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, bioinformatics

I have completed a beginner's course in python and I am working on a problem to improve my coding skills. In this problem, I have to calculate the [GC-skew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GC_skew)  by dividing the entire sequence into subsequences of equal length. I am working in a jupyter notebook.
I have to create a code so that I'll get the number of C's and G's from the sequence and then calculate GC skew in each window. window size = 5kb with an increment of 1kb.

What I have done so far is that first stored the sequence in a list and took user input for length of box/window and increment of the box. Then I tried to create a loop for calculating the number of C's and G's in each window but here I am facing an issue as instead of getting number of C's and G's in a window/box, I am getting number of C's and G's from the entire sequence for number of times the loop is running. I want number total number of C's and total no of G's in each window.

Please suggest how can I get the mentioned number of characters and GC skew for each overlapping sliding window/box. Also is there any concept of sliding window in python which I can use it here?

```
char = []
with open('keratin.txt') as f:
for line in f: 
   line = line.strip()
   for ch in line:
      char.append(ch) 
print(char)  
len(char)

f1 = open('keratin.txt','r')
f2 = open('keratin.txt','a+') 
lob = input('Enter length of box =')  
iob = input('Enter the increment of the box =')    

i=0 
lob = 5000 
iob = 1000   
nob = 1 #no. of boxes 
for i in range (0,len(char)-lob): 
   b = i       
   while( b < lob + i and b < len(char)):          
   nC = 0          
   nG = 0 
   if char[b] == 'C':          
      nC = nC + 1 
   elif char[b] == 'G':             
      nG = nG + 1           
   b = b + 1 
 print(nC)
 print(nG) 
 i = i + iob 
 nob = nob + 1
```

Comment: Within the while loop, you don't have to run the for loop.

Comment: okay, now I have removed the for loop but again the problem is I am not getting total number of C's and G's for a window but it is just giving 1 if the character is either C or G throughout the loop and 0 if not.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra can you please help me out?

Comment: @Trion answer will work.

Comment: For sliding windows, you could be interested in this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque. You may also be interested in this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: @bli  I was actually trying to write the code without using any libraries. Also, I edited the question as it was for overlapping sliding windows, not just sliding windows. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this would help in understanding,

```
number_of_C_and_G = []

# Go from 0 to end, skipping length of box and increment. 0, 6000, 12000 ...
for i in range(0, len(char), lob+inc):
    nC = 0
    nG = 0

    # Go from start to length of box, 0 to 5000, 6000 to 11000 ...
    for j in range(i, lob):
        if char[j] == 'C':
            nC += 1
        else if char[j] == 'G':
            nG += 1
    # Put the value for the box in the list
    number_of_C_and_G.append( (nC, nG) )
```

Comment: thanks. The code worked. Also I edited my original question. As I am still facing an issue.

Comment: @SonaliJain It may be better to ask another question rather than change your question once someone provided a satisfactory answer.